# How do I go about asking my employer about the salary range for a position?

Tags: salary, human-resources

I want to know what the salary ranges are for different levels at my workplace. **Is it OK to ask HR that sort of question? Is it common?**

I'm curious because a position that is similar to mine was advertised, but with a higher salary.

Comment: Please note down what geography you are located in. In Belgium, it is common to ask for a salary range on the first interview, as well as whether you are interviewing with other companies. Contract offers have expiry dates, which can be used to rush other companies into making their offer.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that this is for the company you currently work for.

**Yes, it's OK to ask. But you may not get an answer.**

Some companies have a highly structured salary system, where everybody is assigned a grade, depending on the job they do, and there is a defined salary band for that grade. Governments and large companies are usually of this type. It's usually OK (but not always) to know what the salary bands are for different grades. You won't be able to find out what grade any given person is is, but that isn't difficult to deduce. At the very least you should be able to find out the band for your grade.

Some companies don't have anything that structured, in which case everyone's salary might be different, and you will not be able to find out the salary for any position.

Comment: If your employer is a government agency, they are governed by open records law, so technically you could ask for a list of everyone's salary. Your coworkers might not appreciate it, though. People tend to like that information to be confidential.

Comment: @MJ6 Government has to disclose the salary of any employee? What jurisdiction? And can you point me at a reference, please?

Comment: Federally, there is the Freedom of Information Act, and all 50 states have their own version, usually called an Open Records Act. From the Texas Open Records Act, the "name, sex, ethnicity, salary, title, and dates of employment of each employee and officer of a governmental body" are considered public records. Google "salaries of government employees" followed by the name of your state. Some states have databases of salaries you can search.

Comment: I should add that those databases are not typically maintained by the state, but rather by an outside group that has made open records requests to various government agencies.

Answer (score 3):

This is absolutely an acceptable topic to discuss with either HR or your direct supervisor. Some companies actually publicize (within the company) what the pay range for a particular job is. Some don't. Some allow management to share this information with their staff at their discretion.

There are various ways (salary/statistic websites, friends in the industry, recruiters, job listings) to find out a standard range of salaries for your position in your area. If your company is not willing to discuss what they pay (remember: base salary is only the most basic part of your compensation, and you need to consider the rest of the package) for your skillset and experience, you may want to look elsewhere.

In the past, I've gone to my direct supervisor to ask what the salary range is for my position (and the levels above and below me), and this person was happy to sit down and discuss the topic with me. A healthy workplace will be willing to make it clear to you how they will compensate you and why, and how you can earn more or be promoted (since higher earnings and promotions are directly tied to performance that benefits the employer). I would be hesitant to trust a company that is not willing to discuss how they compensate their employees.

Answer (score 1):

Always keep in mind that salary is just one part of a compensation package. The other position may be in a different sector (where profit margins are higher) or require frequent travel. Maybe they are searching for somebody with special skills, who is more difficult to find. Maybe they need someone urgently, and that is why they are offering higher pay. There are a lot of factors at play here. Before judging your own salary, be sure that you are comparing apples with apples.

Between the lines, your question seems to be *"I saw a position similar to mine with higher advertised pay. What do I do with this knowledge?"*

There will always be people who are paid more than you are. These people may have worn a shirt in a color the CEO liked on the day of their interview, they may have joined the company at the right moment, or they may have negotiated better. **Accept this and move on.**

Now, if you feel you deserve more money (based on thorough market research, not just 'a job ad on LinkedIn'), read these excellent questions:

- [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)
- [I just found out that I am the lowest paid on my team. How do I negotiate a raise without revealing this knowledge?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/3632/i-just-found-out-that-i-am-the-lowest-paid-on-my-team-how-do-i-negotiate-a-rais)
- [Are there humorous, less-confrontational ways to negotiate a starting salary?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/12765/are-there-humorous-less-confrontational-ways-to-negotiate-a-starting-salary)
- [Why is discussing pay such a taboo? How can I get people to talk about concrete figures?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/15397/why-is-discussing-pay-such-a-taboo-how-can-i-get-people-to-talk-about-concrete)

Comment: I think the OP wants to ask the HR department in his current workplace what the salary ranges are for different or specific positions within the company. Not negotiate with recruiters.

Comment: Just a word of caution about gaming your salary higher. If you are unable to meet the expectations of your higher salary, you will likely be in a bad position if business goes sour for the company. But of course try to get your salary to competitive level, if the offer is on the low side.

Comment: @Nix: You are entirely right. This is not a good answer to the question.

Comment: Good points though not answering my question. I basically want to know if I'm paid lower than my colleagues or new hires.

Comment: Chances are you will be paid lower than new hires if you have been employed at the company for some time. This is very common, even though it makes little sense from the employee's perspective

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/1733/93